# Using fork() to read lines from txt file in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork

I am trying to implement a simple program that uses fork() to spawn a child process. The program should allow the parent and child processes to alternate printing lines read from a .txt file and the parent should reap the child process. So far, this is what I have come up with but I am getting a segmentation fault: 11. Can someone help me identify and fix the problem? Thanks!

*Code*

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int status = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    FILE *fp = fopen("/Desktop/read.txt","r");
    char buff[256]="";
    char buff1[256]="";

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process
        if ((fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) != NULL)
            printf ("Read a line in child:\t%s\n", buff);
        else
            printf ("read failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        // parent process
        waitpid (pid, &status, 0);
        while ( (char)fgetc( fp ) != '\n' );
        memset(buff1,0, sizeof(buff1));
        if ((fgets(buff1, sizeof(buff1), fp)) != NULL)
            printf ("Read a line in parent:\t%s\n", buff1);
        else
            printf ("read failed!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        printf("fork() failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your code in a debugger?  That would provide important details about the problem..

Comment: Have you proved that your logic works with two separate programs? Allows you to narrow down whether or not your problem is with `fork` or not.

Comment: Why do you think that two processes will read alternative lines when they are not communicating with each other?

Comment: @DrewDormann GDB returned terminated with unknown signal and it said no symbol table loaded. I'm new to GDB so not sure quite what that means

Comment: just at a glance the first remark, is the two process are trying to open the same file 'fp*', => `segmentation fault` on the spot. try to capture the `errno` and print it, you will get a lot of enlightement, plus read the`fork()` function documentation, also restructure your code, if this code runs in a nuclear plant, it will explode it!.

Comment: Well one of the problems is that neither the parent nor the child ever try to read or print more than one line, so it isn't clear how the whole process can be called "alternating". Another problem is that you don't check whether your calls to library functions succeed (if you don't check you don't care, right?)

Comment: I just tested and your app appears to work for me (though you forgot `#include <sys/wait.h>`). I was able to reproduce a segmentation fault by trying to open a file that doesn't exist. So I would verify that `/Desktop/read.txt` is actually there and perhaps add some code to handle when `fopen()` fails.

Comment: Anyway, should `else printf ("read failed!\n"); exit(1);` be braced as `else { printf ("read failed!\n"); exit(1); }` ?

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry folks, I don't need it to alternate lines (plural). I just need it to print one via parent and the other via child. The code I posted does that and removing /Desktop/ fixes the segmentation fault and allows compilation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )` to avoid getting the two warnings from the compiler about the unused parameters

Comment: when displaying information about an error condition: 1) always output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) when the error was from a system function, like `fork()`, use `perror( "error message" );`  so both the error message AND the reason the system thinks the function failed are output to `stderr`.  Note: there should be no intervening functions calls, as they may change the value in `errno` which would cause `perror()` (or `strerror()`) to output the wrong information

Comment: regarding: `while ( (char)fgetc( fp ) != '\n' );`  1) no need to cast to `char`.  2) also need to be checking for `EOF`.  Suggest:  `int ch; while( (ch = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF  && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: regarding: `memset(buff1,0, sizeof(buff1));`  this statement is not needed as the following call to `fgets()` will overlay the contents of `buff1`

Comment: regarding: `printf ("read failed!\n");`  it is not `read` that failed. and such error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  Suggest: `perror( "fgets in parent failed" );`

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the statements: 1) `#include <sys/types.h>` 2) `#include <sys/stat.h>`  3) `#include <fcntl.h>`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.